# to_excel on desktop regardless of the user

Tags: python, pandas

Is there a way to use pandas `to_excel` function to write to the desktop, no matter which user is running the script? I've found answers for VBA but nothing for python or pandas.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`pandas.DataFrame.to_excel()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.13.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html) requires an argument `excel_writer` which is either a file path or an existing ExcelWriter-object.

Just give the path as the argument:

```
>>> df.to_excel('path_to_your_file.xls')
```

More specifically, to write to the users desktop, use [`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser):

```
>>> path = os.path.join(os.path.expanduser("~"), "Desktop", "your_file.xls")
>>> df.to_excel(path)
```

[`os.path.expanduser`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.expanduser) guarantees that you'll get the home directory of the user on POSIX and windows but there are many corner cases which you should take into account.

For example on windows, if the users home directory is managed via active directory, you'll get the home directory which resides on the network drive, and there might not be a `Desktop` -folder. Similarily linux users have free hands to rename or delete their folder called `Desktop`. Or they might not even have a `Desktop` folder, as linux doesn't need a window manager to run.

Comment: So assuming they have their own personal folder on a network drive that's their home, that would cause it to be placed there in a folder named desktop rather than their local desktop?

Comment: Probably. However if they have a desktop folder on the network drive that's their home, then most likely that desktop folder is the one you want. This is usually company policy stuff and is quite well standardized.

Comment: Tested it out, and it dropped on the local desktop. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This depends on your operating system.

You're saying you'd like to save the file on the desktop of the user who is running the script right?

On linux (not sure if this is true of every distribution) you could pass in "~/desktop/my_file.xls" as the path where you're saving the file